# How do I iterate and list XML node attributes?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I'm loading into an XmlDocument and need to get a list of all the attributes on nodes with a specific name.

```
   <shirts>
        <product ID="123" Name="tee" Serial="5678"/>
        <product ID="456" Name="crew" Serial="4566"/>
     </shirts>
    <pants>
         <product ID="123" Name="jeans" Serial="1243" Color="blue"/>
         <product ID="123" Name="dress" Serial="3455" Color="black"/>
         <product ID="123" Name="shorts" Serial="6654" Color="grey"/>
    </pants>
```

From this I need a list of all the "product" attributes.  Result looking like:

```
ID
Name
Serial
Color
```

I don't need the values, just the attributes themselves.  I'm using C# and Winforms.  I know how to get the attribute values but not sure how it's done to get the attribute names themselves.  How do I do that?

Comment: What he said. Also, I'd suggest you use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`, if possible. It's easier to use.

Comment: Simple on purpose as an example.  I did not know about LINQ to XML, that's all I needed to know.  I have no issue researching and learning but with no direction on even the topic to investigate it's difficult.  I didn't want code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to switch to using the `System.Xml.Linq` classes, you can use LINQ to XML to get what you want:

```cs
var xml = XElement.Load(xmlFileName);
var attrNames = (
    from p in xml.Descendants("product")
    from a in p.Attributes()
    select a.Name
).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LinqToXml

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("File.xml");

var attributes = doc.Element("product").Attributes();

foreach (var item in attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

It takes the list of attributes from the first "product" node. if the "product" nodes have different attributes, you need collect all then distinct the list result:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("File.xml");

var attributes = doc.Elements("product").SelectMany(x => x.Attributes());

var uniqAtt = attributes.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct();

foreach (var item in uniqAtt)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```